# How do I force any user accessing my PostgreSQL database to provide a password?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my Rails app, database.yml:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: minecraft-kingdoms_development
  username: jacobcrofts
  password: <%= ENV['MINECRAFT-KINGDOMS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

The password is supplied by an environment variable, which I load automatically.

upon \du in the Postgres console:

```
 Role name |                   Attributes                   |
-----------+------------------------------------------------+
jacobcrofts| Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication |
```

I am worried because my Java plugin is able to access the database without providing a password. All it needs is the correct host and username, and any password (or none at all) will allow my plugin to establish a connection to the database.

I want to force my Java plugin to provide a password upon accessing my database for obvious security reasons. How can I do this? Why isn't providing a password field in database.yml sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I found out why this is happening. Postgres is configured to trust any user connecting from localhost, and I am running my server on localhost. Credit to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834278/how-is-my-ruby-on-rails-app-able-to-access-the-database-without-the-password).